# How to return a list of strings randomly from a given string?

Tags: python, string, random

```
import random
def create_code(characters):
    return list(random.choice(characters)*4)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    characters = 'ygobpr'
    print create_code(characters)
```

How to return a list of 4 strings, each random, from the given string  `characters = 'ygobpr'`?

Comment: What length should each string be ?

Comment: each string should just be one letter out of the string 'ygobpr'

Comment: `random.sample(characters, 4)`

Comment: oh thanks i completely forgot about that function sample

Comment: Are repetitions allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> each string should just be one letter out of the string 'ygobpr' –

You can just use `random.sample()` directly:

```
In [8]: random.sample(characters, 4)
Out[8]: ['y', 'b', 'o', 'p']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of random characters as following:

```
import random
def create_code(characters):
    return list(random.choice(characters) for n in xrange(4))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    characters = 'ygobpr'
    print create_code(characters)
```